# What is the maximum number of url parameters that can be added to the exclusion list for google analytics

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I set up a profile for Google Analytics.  I have several dozen url parameters that various pages use and I want to exclude.  Luckily, google has a field you can modify under the general profile settings `[Exclude URL Query Parameters:]`.  Of the several dozen items I have they are all working, and not being considered part of the URL.  Except for the parameter `propid`

I added `propid` to the comma separated list on Monday.  But, everyday when I check GA, sure enough they are coming through with that parameter still attached.

So, am I trying to exclude too many parameters? I couldn't find any documentation on GA's site to say there was a limit.

**here is the exact content of the `exclude URL Query parameter field`**
There reason there are so many is the bh before me didn't know the difference between get/post.

`propid,account,pp,kw1,kw2,kw3,sortby,page,msg,sd,ed,ea,ec,sc,subname,subcode,sa,qc,type,code,propid,acct,minbr,maxbr,minfb,maxfb,minhb,maxhb,minrm,maxrm,minst,maxst,minun,maxun,minyb,maxyb,minla,maxla,minba,maxba,minuc,maxuc,card,print,year,type`

**update**

I thought after more time had passed the "bad data" would fall of of GA.  But as of yesterday it is still reporting on the propid querystring value despite adding that as well as other variables to the exclude list.

**update2**

I found this post on google https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=72de4afc7b734c4e&hl=en

It reads that the field only allows 255 char,  Ok. Problem Solved.  Except my field of values is only 247 charcters..  ARGGGHH!

**Update 3 **

So Here is the code I've added to the googleAnalytics.asp include page that goes at the top of everyone of my asp classic pages.  Can anyone see a flaw in the design?  I don't care about ANY query string info. (it could have been named *.inc, but I like having intellisense working)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% GAPageDisplayName = REQUEST.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") %> 
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20842347-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.sc-pa.com']);
    <% if GAPageDisplayName <> "" then %> 
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','<%=GAPageDisplayName %>']);
    <% else %>
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    <% end if %>


    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

**Update 4**

I'll only accept an answer if you will include something talking to the original question.  My question was very specific, I wanted to know exactly the number of characters google allows.  Everything I included in my original question body was simply to backfill the question to put everything in context.

Comment: Adding updates to the top of your question makes it very hard to understand for people seeing it the first time. Did you delete the actual question in your updates? Is the title your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest an alternate solution to the reliance on manually excluding all of these (and feasibly *any* string ever used)?

I'd suggest passing a parameter to the trackPageView function to 'force' the recording of a manually/programatically set 'page name' value. 
Whereas by default, GA records/defines a page based on a unique URL, the inclusion of a pagename parameter would associate all pageviews of a page with that parameter as pageviews to a single page.

For example, standard GA pageview code looks like this: `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`, whereas the inclusion of a specific page name looks like this: `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'Homepage']);`. With the latter, presuming that the homepage is at www.site.com, regardless of how that page is accessed GA will always consolidate all pageview stats for it as 'Homepage'. So, www.site.com/index.php, www.site.com/?a=b and www.site.com/?1=2&x=y will always report as 'Homepage' as if it was one page.

The only drawback here is that you need to be incredibly careful around any occurences of pagination, nested pages, content swapping, site search, or any functionality which may in fact rely on the use of query strings; you may need to consider some logic on how the page name values are output, rather than attempting to define on a per-page basis depending on the site of your site(s).

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that you have `propid` listed twice in the exclusion field?  Once at the beginning and then again about one-third of the way through.  That's the only thing that stands out to me.  See what happens if you remove either of these.

You also have `type` duplicated, so if the above fixes the problem for `propid`, also consider removing the second `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Google limits the characters in the "Exclude Url Query" field (2048 characters max), not the number of queries. I had the same issue you're having and what I discovered was that I had populated my query string parameter list based on the pagenames in my pages report. Well those pagenames first pass through a view-level lowercase filter that I have set up. And since the "Exclude URL Query" field is case sensitive, some of the parameters were getting through. Hopefully this helps.